# How to find a lost Android phone?

Tags: lost-phone

My father's Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge was stolen, and we're having a hard time finding it. He logged on Find My Device and has registered it, but the phone is obviously not connected to the wifi to trace it. It has SMS, and can be called, but the caller keeps hanging it up. Only a matter of time till the caller shuts down the phone and can never be traced. Any options?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [lost-phone tag-wiki](/tags/lost-phone/info) and its links? As you can imagine, you're not the first one in such a situation – so others already have collected details on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can track your phone using his IMEI, usually found in the box of the phone itself, try to use this [website](http://trackmyimei.com)
and insert there your IMEI